# Boot configuration mystery

Tags: boot, configuration

Machine  Acer Aspire 7740G laptop.
Dual boot with Ubuntu 19.10 and Win 10 (purely because I have a couple of 'must have' apps that are only available in Win---ws).
System runs perfectly.

I wanted to do some Software Defined Radio work and came across DragonOS - a compilation of SDR apps built into DragonOS - an installable 
OS package built on LUbuntu 18.04.

As I had some spare space at the end of the SSD, I thought I'd install it and have a complete assortment of SDR apps so went ahead. It installed perfectly but created a new Boot setup and  put itself at the top of the boot order and became the default option which meant that every time I started the machine, it went into DragonOS which I did not want.

I tried Grub customizer from my 19.10 installation but that had no effect because I realized I need to alter the DragoOS boot configuration not the 19.10.

So, I booted into DragonOS and tried to install Boot-repair but no matter what I tried, I couldn't even get the repository added - the required directories were not present.

Without doing some drastic deleting and putting my working system at risk, I don't quite know what to do. I need to get the system back to 'looking' at the 19.10 boot configuration but don't know how to do that.

Would appreciate any good advice!

Comment: I see someone answered below which will hopefully solve the issue. If not I have had success in the past fixing dual-boot issues with the boot repair tool. Mainly when a windows update messed up the dual boot. Just boot using ubuntu cd/dvd/usb and then install/run the tool. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default grub boot entry from the console in DragonOS.

First, take a look inside `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to see what exactly the boot entry is called, e.g. for

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' [options] {
```

the name would be `Ubuntu`.

Then, make a backup copy of `/etc/default/grub`:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
```

Then edit the file using `nano` or the text editor of your choice:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that contains

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=xxxxxx
```

and change whatever is in `xxxxxx` to the name you found in the first step.

Finally,

```
sudo update-grub
```

And reboot!

Comment: Thank you Joe for your quick reply but, although I did exactly what you said, it made no difference - same boot order.

Comment: The original GRUB_DEFAULT= statement was = 0 (GRUB_DEFAULT=0) - I changed that to Ubuntu which was what I found in /boot/grub/grub.cfg (menuentry 'Ubuntu'....).

Comment: I guess what happened when I installed DragonOS is that it overwrote the original Boot configuration and 'pointed' to DragonOS on SDA8 as the default system to boot up. What I need to do is to get that default entry to point to my 'main' / original Ubuntu system on SDA5. Would it not be possible to do some file swapping somehow to restore the original configuration or is that naive ?